# Loading Multiple files using EMF resource load?

Tags: eclipse, emf

I have a requirement where in the data to be loaded on to the model is
distributed in multiple files, is it possible to load multiple files on to
the same model. Using EMF Resource load

if yes? can someone please guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you have a Model distributed in multiple files, when you load the file that containt the root model element, all children are loaded althought they are contain in the distributed files.